# swipe left/right uiview without storyboard

Tags: swift3, uiview, swift4, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I want to swipe right to show another view and swipe left to get back to first view, **Without using storyboard** 
like this example:

[image]

Could someone show me how to do that with swift 4

Comment: I think you used scrollview and made custom to it.

Comment: @Salah did you find an answer yet? Did you try my answer below?

Comment: Hello sorry i was busy, I didn't understand your answer sorry, I have small view like this [Click here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chthai64/SwipeRevealLayout/master/art/demo_same.gif) I want to drag right to show buttons, and then drag left to get back, any idea how it works? And thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Salah The link that you just posted is completely different than the question you just asked. The one above is talking about how to swipe a scroll view to get back to the beginning and the "Click Here" is how to present views that are off screen using swipe. Which is it?

Comment: @SpenserArn I want the easiest way to do like "Click here" I have a small view have Label on it, when i drag right i want to show buttons and hide label, I dont want swipe to show\hide, I want when you keep dragging to right buttons appearing from left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume that if you were to use a swipe gesture, you would do something like:

```
let swipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
let scrollView = UIScrollView()

swipeGesture.direction = .right
swipeGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(scrollToBeginning))

@objc func scrollToBeginning() {            
    scrollView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: true)
}
```

Or using `scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1), animated: true)`